# Changing keyboard layout to Dvorak in Ubuntu-server

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-server, dvorak

I want to set my keyboard layout to Dvorak. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: My first impulse was to add another vote but having had to switch keyboard layouts on a Debian server (from French to US) makes me think this can equally be an SF question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this more straightforward and simple:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Only this solution actually made things persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 8):

This will guide you through the process of selecting different keyboard layouts:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Maybe you will need to install console-data.

```
$ sudo apt-get install console-data
```

If you want to make changes permanent then you can use:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 13.04

Switch to Dvorak:

```
setxkbmap dvorak
```

Switch back:

```
setxkbmap us
;dkbvnmar f;   # How to type 'setxkbmap us' in Dvorak while looking at a US Keyboard (updated)
```

Works locally on my Ubuntu machine. Haven't tested on ubuntu-server, but this is a prevalent search result for "dvorak keyboard linux"

Comment: You're how to type it in Dvorak if you're looking at a US keyboard is wrong. If you type `setxkbmap us` on a Qwerty keyboard with Dvorak settings, you will see `o.yqtxmal go` appear on your terminal. What you want, though, is the reverse: which key on the Qwerty keyboard gets the Dvorak key I want? The correct text is: `;dkbvnmar f;`. I've tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like this will work, too:

`$ sudo loadkeys dvorak`

Hat tip to http://ma.tt/2004/01/dvorak-on-linux-console/

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't permanently alter your machine -- good for making scripts that switch keyboard layouts.